# Incorrect syntax error near WHERE

Tags: c#, rdlc

I would like to display new column "Total" in RDLC report,
Actually the field use to calculate the total is a different dataset.
I have created a data table and insert the fields(including "total") that I want to display in report into it.
WHen I execute the program, the error show "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

```
string sql = "SELECT customer.customer, 
                     customer.imp_license_no, 
                     customer.psq_level,           
                     whbal.std_weight, 
                     whbal.qty_good,  
                     whbal.qty_slack, 
                     total FROM (
              SELECT((qty_good+qty_slack)*std_weight/1000) AS Total FROM whbal 
              WHERE warehouse='SKW') customer 
              INNER JOIN whbal 
              WHERE customer.customer=whbal.customer AND customer.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2";

        SqlCommand custcom = new SqlCommand(sql, myconnection);

        custcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust1", cboFrom.SelectedValue.ToString());
        custcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust2", cboTo.SelectedValue.ToString());

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(custcom);
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        da.Fill(ds, "customer1");
        da.Fill(ds, "whbal");

        myconnection.Close();

        reportViewer1.Reset();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "WindowsFormsApplication1.Report1.rdlc";
        reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables["Customer1"]));
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",ds.Tables["whbal"]));

        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Do anyone know what is the problem and pls help to comment.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The first thing I do when I encounter SQL issues is to copy and paste the SQL into Enterprise Manager to see if the SQL will run, just to simplify the problem.

Comment: total FROM ( looks weird, why is a FROM there?

Comment: I was thinking do the calculation in From statement, and select the "total" value from it. But it sems like not work

Comment: string sql = "SELECT customer.customer, customer.imp_license_no, customer.psq_level, whbal.std_weight, whbal.qty_good, whbal.qty_slack, SELECT((qty_good+qty_slack)*std_weight/1000) AS Total FROM whbal WHERE warehouse='SKW', customer INNER JOIN whbal WHERE customer.customer=whbal.customer AND customer.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2";

I change to this query, but another error show up: "Incorrect syntax near SELECT", "Incorrect syntax near ','"

Comment: Your subquery syntax is wrong. See here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/subqueries-in-sql-server/

Comment: @matthew Lock I alrdy make changes but got another error, seems like the error is caused by the dataset, Error:"Column 'whbal.qty_slack' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Can I ask, if i wan use two dataset in one rdlc report, how should I do? I tried do the calculation in report expression instead of query, but the report could not read it, probably different dataset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using `ON` for the `INNER JOIN`?

```
INNER JOIN whbal ON customer.customer = whbal.customer AND 
                    customer.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2";
```

Comment: You can leave out ON in an INNER JOIN and do the "join" on the where clause. It's sloppy though.

Comment: @MatthewLock - Didn't know that and looks sort of wrong. I was thinking since he got the message `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE` the error was in the `INNER JOIN` clause.

Comment: @MatthewLock I don't think you can leave out ON in an INNER JOIN. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx says "A simplified ISO FROM clause join syntax is: FROM first_table join_type second_table [ON (join_condition)]"